# How do I extend an image over three monitors?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, display, eyefinity

So I have three monitors:

- One with a HDMI monitor (my "main" one)
- One with VGA
- One with the white (and somewhat larger) VGA looking cable

I have the [AMD RADEON HD 6450](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/amd-radeon-hd-6000/hd-6450/pages/amd-radeon-hd-6450-overview.aspx). This has eyefinity, which supports up to four monitors.

If I plug in more than one monitor, it disconnects the other non-main one. In the catalyst control center, if I click "Extend" on the non-working monitor, I get an error:

```
To extend the desktop, a desktop or display must be disabled.
```

With the options "Continue" or "Cancel". Both do what you could probably imagine. How do I use three monitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use three monitors with [AMD Eyefinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyefinity#Multi-display_technologies) at least one of them has to use the display port (either mini or full). This table is in the wikipedia article for 5800 cards but I am pretty sure it applies to the 6450 as well:

[image: table]

If you don't have a monitor with display port as an input you can get an active DisplayPort to DVI-D adapter. I have a 6950 with my main monitor using HDMI one side monitor using DVI-D and the other using this [adaptor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004071ZXA) to DVI. It works very nice the only downside being that occasionally when I wake the computer from sleep the monitor on the adapter doesn't wake up. If I unplug and replug the adapter it works.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know you need a Display Port connection to use 3 Monitors the same time (so 1 Monitor VGA, the next HDMI and the 3rd must be Display Port).

AMD explains this here:

http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/how-to/Pages/set-up.aspx